# Cross-site queries on SEDE fail with "The EXECUTE permission was denied"

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I just noticed that any [cross-site queries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/allow-cross-site-queries-in-data-explorer) using dynamically generated SQL on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com) now fail with the error message:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_executesql', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

[Typically](https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/355774/cross-site-query-template) this message is repeated many times as the code tries to loop over all SE sites:

[image: Screenshot]

I don't know exactly when this stopped working, but it must've been sometime within the last two months, as it was still working fine in mid-August.

I'm not sure if this technically constitutes a bug, since AFAIK this feature was never explicitly supported.  However, the change did break a number of useful queries, such as [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/983612/all-my-posts-on-the-se-network-with-markdown-and-html-content-plus-editors-and-s) for [making a backup of all your posts on the SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320943) and [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209965/duplicates-of-deleted-questions) that lists duplicates of deleted questions and uses the cross-site query feature to exclude migrated questions.  (I've edited the latter query to temporarily disable the cross-site part, so that it at least mostly works.)

So my questions are:

1. Can this feature please be re-enabled (e.g.) by adding the necessary permissions?
2. If not, is there any work-around?

---

Ps. I just found [this related bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333145/network-wide-queries-dont-work-on-the-sede) from early September which looks similar, but shows a different error message and is marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).  Apparently this isn't the first time this feature broke recently.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what caused this and when. Let me see what I can do to unstick this.

Comment: I kinda hope the answer involves an actual stick ...

Comment: @bart I will never give away my secrets

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be resolved now. Recently [we restricted access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333148/164200) to many of the system objects inside of SEDE and the change impacted the ability to execute that stored procedure.

I updated the permissions this morning and you should be able to execute `sp_executesql` again.

Thanks for reporting it.

Side Note: Another way to execute dynamic SQL is to use `exec(@querystring)` or `execute(@querystring)` and then you're not executing a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that my cross-site queries are working again. Also, special thanks for going the extra mile and providing the alternate solution. Unfortunately my T-SQL skills are rather weak, as I use it only on SEDE, so a lot of my "fancier" code tends to be of the copy-paste or "monkey see, monkey do" variety. It's always nice to learn new and (possibly) better ways of doing things.

Comment: Ps. Now that I can actually test it, [here's a post describing my latest cross-site monstrosity](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30790) that finds broken links to questions and answers between different SE sites. Maybe someone will find it useful. :)